# IEEEtran command list along with example?

Tags: ieeetran

I am new to Latex and have started to write a paper in `IEEEtran` format. But i don't know which command to be used for which purpose.  So, anybody could suggest me a link where i can get a complete example (about including images, references  etc.)

I have read this [**link**](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esteffan/personal/tmp/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) which is quite good but it doesn't give a working example. My main confusions are about including images/figures and references.

**What i need:** It would be so helpful if i could get the source code of the link mentioned above (i mean something similar) so that i can understand the role of each command and the proper way to use it.

Comment: I strongly advice you to read some basic LaTeX introduction to get you started. See it as an investment.

Comment: And later `texdoc ieeetran` or [Package Documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf)

Comment: @Johannes_B: Thanks, but the link which i have mentioned is also written by the same person and explains the similar stuff. But what i need is to get its source code so that i can see what line is doing what?

Comment: You can search for `IEEEtran.cls` on your computer and read the code but if you are new there is not much you can learn from it.

Comment: I take it you are not using LyX, so I removed the [tag:lyx-layouts] tag.

Answer (score 1):

The `IEEEtran` class comes with multiple examples file, like:

http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bare_jrnl_transmag.tex